# Invalid arguments no host specified in URI

Tags: flutter

```
Image.network(
   widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!,
   height: 210.0,
   fit: BoxFit.cover,
   errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,StackTrace? stackTrace) {
     return const Text('');
    },
 [firebase screenshot of from where i want to fetch image. Iwant fech from 'thumbnailUrl'.][1]),
```

[firebase screenshot of from where i want to fetch the image. I want fetch from 'thumbnailUrl'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGHBs.png)

[app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrOQO.jpg)

Iam trying to fetch the image from firebase to app but unable to see it.. I have attched the code with images .please help me fix this

Comment: As requested already in your earlier question, please print the value of `widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!`.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to print.. i have tried to print it throws error

Comment: `print(widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!)`.  What is the error?  If you get an error, most likely it's because you're using `!` on `null`. `!` is expected to be used when you can logically guarantee that a variable is *not* `null`.

Comment: Additionally, if you don't understand comments to your original question, you should comment on or edit your original question, not post new ones.  Please discuss this there.

Comment: Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
              Image.network(
                           ^

Comment: Image.network(
                print(widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!),
                  widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!,
                  height: 210.0,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  // errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                  //   return const Text('');
                  //   },
              ),                   for this code

Comment: Please Help me fix this

Comment: Call `print(widget.model!.thumbnailUrl!);` *before* you call `Image.network`, not as an *argument* to `Image.network`.  Also, as I stated before, please discuss this in your original question.

Comment: Okay. I did not know how to edit so i added another question..! I'll try to print the value..